# Ruby string operate (delimeter)

Tags: ruby

I have a string like this:

```
14.015_KNECHT_178178
```

How can I split it so that:

```
art = 14.015
man = KNECHT
```

As you see the delimeter is `_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
art,man= "14.015_KNECHT_178178".split(/_/)
```

for more details of [#split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split) here

Answer (score 2):

string#split can do this.

```
>> (art,man,foo) = "14.015_KNECHT_178178".split '_'
=> ["14.015", "KNECHT", "178178"]
>> p art
"14.015"
=> "14.015"
>> p man
"KNECHT"
=> "KNECHT"
>> p foo
"178178"
=> "178178"
```